# Why two radio buttons are not aligned together when one of them uses col-sm-4 and other uses offset-sm-4?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code: [Codeply link](https://www.codeply.com/p/TcjR3xBOXx)

The problem is that as you can see my radio buttons are not aligned together. First label uses uses `col-sm-4` and the other one (without a label) uses `offset-sm-4`.

My expected result was that the second button will get the margin as the first label and will align with the first radio button...

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that they are not lining up is your use of `text-center` on your `<section>` element. It's causing the content of `col-sm-8` to center itself relative to its width, and since your second radio element is shorter (in characters) than the previous it appears offset.

With that being said, unless these two radio inputs are intended to be for different inputs (rather than different values for the same input) I would highly recommend placing them in the same `.form-group`.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <section class="col-12 col-md-10 col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group form-row">
        <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">My label</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
            <label class="custom-control-label">This is text 1</label>
          </div>

          <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
            <label class="custom-control-label">Text2</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </section>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```